# How do i do a quest in Candy Crush Saga

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have been playing Candy Crush Saga for awhile I just finished level 35. My friend had been playing the quests and it gave me the quest option at first, but my friend said that she could do a quest every 24 hours so I completed the first quest and it said I could do another one in 24 hours so I went back in 24 hours but didn't get that choice again.  How do I get that option back again?

Comment: Which device are you playing on? PC, Android, iOS?

Answer (score 7):

These are referred to as "**[Mystery Quests](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/unlocking-new-episodes-in-candy-crush-saga-mystery-quests/)**" by the game.  When you tap on the icon for the plane (or train, boat, etc) that is just past the last level you've cleared, you should see a menu pop up.

On this menu you should have at *least* two options.  One will be to pay to unlock the next episode, and the other will be to connect to Facebook and ask your friends for help.

The third option **only appears if you are playing on a mobile device (iPhone, iPad, Android, etc) and not logged into Facebook inside Candy Crush Saga.**  This is the option to play a Mystery Quest.

If you don't see this third option, log out of Facebook by:

1. From the "Map" screen, tap the arrow icon in the lower left.  This brings up a small menu.
2. Tap the red "Door" icon, which will take you back to the main menu.
3. Tap the arrow icon in the lower left again to bring up the small menu.
4. Tap the green "Gear" icon to bring up another menu.
5. Scroll this menu down to the bottom and tap the Facebook icon which should say "Log out"

Then you should be able to go back into the game, and tap the plane/train/boat/etc icon and see the Mystery Quest option.

Answer (score 2):

if you are connected to Facebook it will not give you the quests option.  turn Internet off on your device then open candy crush again

Answer (score 0):

If you've completed level 35, selecting level 36 (or what looks like an unavailable level with a biplane icon nearby) should bring up the standard "Unlock more levels" screen with facebook, unlock now (via purchase) and play quests option - even if quests are unavailable until the next day.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Candy crush saga level 36 unlock]

Comment: I'm using a nook HD

Comment: This did not bring up the quest option

Comment: You can't be logged into facebook for the quests option to show.