# Is there a way to force a sync between Facebook and your mobile device?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I play on both my desktop, through Facebook, and on the Android Candy Crush Saga app.

The app is linked to my Facebook account.

Occasionally the two accounts stop synchronizing for a while, up to a few days.  During this time, levels unlocked on one platform will not be unlocked on the other.

Once the two platforms manage to synch back up, any unlocked levels become available on both platforms.

However, now I'm at the point where I need 3 tickets to unlock the next level on my phone, but am 1 level shy of that point on Facebook.

I've gotten 3 friends to provide tickets, but only two show up on my phone.

All three show up as having provided tickets to level 156 on Facebook, but I can't proceed because it isn't giving me credit for having completed level 155.

Is there a way to force the two platforms to synch up?  Rebooting my phone or pressing the synch button within the phone app do not fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not play on Android, but you may have success signing out of Facebook from the Candy Crush Saga app, and then re-signing in.  Via iOS, this is a scroll down option from the "Arrow" menu -> "Gear" sub-menu on the main title screen.  I regularly use this method to re-sync via my iOS device (and it seems most things are similar on the Android variant).

This can also be very useful on the mobile device versions, as it gives you the option to play "**[Mystery Quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/how-do-i-do-a-quest-in-candy-crush-saga)**" instead of getting tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of smart phone you have. I have an iPhone 3 and laptop. Both have FB and Candy Crush Saga. And of course, same issue with others, the iPhone's CCS refused to sync after I changed the FB password from my laptop. Shortly after that, I changed the password setting of FB on my iPhone to match with FB on laptop. Still not synched.

I continued playing CCS on both iPhone and laptop (in FB). The laptop advanced a few levels higher than from the iPhone. I got stuck at the unlocking level 245 for a few days and then it let me pass through, onto 247. The iPhone CCS still stuck at 244. After pulling a few hair and scratching the head, I decided to do something. Below is the simple solution that I just performed today on my iPhone:

- Delete CCS (with iPhone setting still allows CCS to access FB).
- Download a fresh CCS from iTunes (wherever, really).
- Launched CCS. It asked to connect to FB. I accepted it.

That was it. After CCS synched with FB, CCS on my iPhone gets the same level as on FB. And that is nice because I can't get past 244. I needed too much luck and it didn't come.

So, the problem is the FB password change. But it is a small problem indeed. You only lose levels ONLY IF CCS on your smart phone is higher than from FB. Otherwise, just delete it and reinstall.