# Will I need an airplane ticket more than once?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

In Candy Crush, I need an airplane ticket to go to level 36. Is that the only time that I will have to decide to ask my friends on Facebook or pay the 99 cents?

Answer (score 3):

Nah, it won't be the only time. There is more stuff like this later in the game.

One option I did was I played the three quests to pass. It takes longer, but it saves you paying and hassling your friends :p

Comment: @justin In case you are wondering what a Mystery Quest is, or how to access them - see the question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/how-do-i-do-a-quest-in-candy-crush-saga).

Answer (score 0):

These actually happen every 15 levels, all the way up to level 500. You even have to unlock something after Level 500, but I haven't gotten far enough to tell you what that unlocks...